# Run script using Qt Creator like environment

Tags: linux, bash, qt, qt-creator

I try to run a deployment script using KDE Neon. I have started the script manually from bash and I got an error qmake would be not found.

When trying to run qmake directly from the bash I get the following error:

```
$ qmake -v
qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake': No such file or directory
```

That `bin` folder is almost empty and contains no qmake. In the path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/` a full Qt installation can be found but no qmake as well. `/usr/bin/qmake` obviously is a link that is pointing to the missing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake`.

qmake works fine when using Qt Creator. The binary used by Qt Creator is `/home/<user>/Qt/5.10.0/gcc_64/bin/qmake`.

Obviously the `/usr/...` Qt installations aren't complete. First I thought about how to complete the installations and how to switch from Qt4 to Qt5. However Qt Creator obviously is able to use its own `/home/...` located Qt environment anyway and I would like to use it too when running a script outside Qt Creator.

Is there a way I can start scripts from bash using the same Qt environment as Qt Creator (without modifying the OS configuration)?

Comment: `/home/<user>/Qt/5.10.0/gcc_64/bin/qmake yourpro.pro` is that not working for you? If you use `qmake` it will be picked up from `/usr/..` when you have a link.

Comment: @user3606329 I can't use an absolute qmake path. I am using a tool named linuxdeployqt that indirectly calls qmake from path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QtCreator itself only modifies the environemt, i.e. it sets

```
export PATH="/home/<user>/Qt/5.10.0/gcc_64/bin:$PATH"
export QTDIR="/home/<user>/Qt/5.10.0/gcc_64"
```

This can be verified by checking the "Build Environment" section in the "Projects" tab. When checking the environment for the run configuration there is one more that is needed for the compiled applications to find the correct `.so` files (The build env. is used to run build tools. The run env. is used to run the compiled application).

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/home/<user>/Qt/5.10.0/gcc_64/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

So in order to easily use qmake/... from the command line, just create a script that sets these (and possibly others you defined for your build in QtCreator) and source it before compiling and it should work.

```
source ~/qt-home-init.sh
qmake ...
```